# Python non-blocking socket - Receiving message after delay

Tags: python, sockets, time, network-programming, nonblocking

I am trying to make my client receive a message from my server using a non-blocking Socket, however, the client is only allowed to check for new messages once every second. The server first sends the size of the message as an integer, and then the message itself.

This is the code on my client:

```
server = ('192.168.1.220', 4000)
buf_size = 16384
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect(server)
sock.setblocking(0) 

while True:
    message = b''
    size = None

    try:
        size = int(sock.recv(buf_size).decode('utf-8'))
    except:
        pass
    
    if size:
        while len(message) < size:
            try:
                data = sock.recv(buf_size)
                message += data
            except:
                pass

    if len(message) > 0:
        print(message)
    
    #time.sleep(1)
```

This works as it is, however, if I uncomment the 1 second delay at the end of the outer while loop (`time.sleep(1)`), the client does not receive any messages the server sends anymore (there are no errors either).

Why does the delay break the code here? I assume the messages sent to the client will remain in the stream until they are read by the `recv()` method. Am I misunderstanding the way nonblocking sockets work? How would I be able to achieve this instead?

Comment: *...This works as it is...* That is very unlikely. The problem is the line `size = int(sock.recv(buf_size).decode('utf-8'))`. This `recv()` will likely return the length bytes and a big chunk of the message that follows it. It also might return just one byte of the length. If your server does one send for the length and another send for the message there is no guarantee that the client will receive it that way. It might receive everything in the first call to `recv`. TCP does not preserve these kinds of boundaries, it is a streaming protocol.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Although this is working without the delay, what you just said was the reason the time delay broke it. Without the delay the loop ran fast enough so that the client could pick up first message containing the size before the second message was appended to it like you described, but with the delay the size variable contained a part of the next message and the TypeError in converting it to an integer was hidden by the try/catch block. I fixed it by sending the first message containing the size as 16 bytes and only reading the first 16 bytes in my client.

Comment: Why check for messages at all? Why not either use blocking mode or `select()`.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne The time.sleep() call is meant to simulate other stuff the client will be doing in between checking for messages and blocking mode would prevent that.